# Azure API Management CSRF Policy

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm trying to create an inbound policy to pass my x-csrf-token to a Post method. However, when i check the tracing, i'm getting null value for the x-csrf-token.
I'm using the snippet given here in the https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/examples/Get%20X-CSRF%20token%20from%20SAP%20gateway%20using%20send%20request.policy.xml.

Have anyone come across this issue before?

```html
<!--
    IMPORTANT:
    - Policy elements can appear only within the <inbound>, <outbound>, <backend> section elements.
    - To apply a policy to the incoming request (before it is forwarded to the backend service), place a corresponding policy element within the <inbound> section element.
    - To apply a policy to the outgoing response (before it is sent back to the caller), place a corresponding policy element within the <outbound> section element.
    - To add a policy, place the cursor at the desired insertion point and select a policy from the sidebar.
    - To remove a policy, delete the corresponding policy statement from the policy document.
    - Position the <base> element within a section element to inherit all policies from the corresponding section element in the enclosing scope.
    - Remove the <base> element to prevent inheriting policies from the corresponding section element in the enclosing scope.
    - Policies are applied in the order of their appearance, from the top down.
    - Comments within policy elements are not supported and may disappear. Place your comments between policy elements or at a higher level scope.
-->
<!-- The policy defined in this file shows how to implement X-CSRF pattern used by many APIs. The example is specific to SAP Gateway.  -->
<!--    Detailed description of the scenario and solution can be found on: -->
<!--      https://github.com/MartinPankraz/AzureSAPODataReader. -->
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <authentication-basic username="{{SAP-test-user}}" password="{{SAP-test-PW}}" />
        <set-variable name="checkRequestUrl" value="@(context.Request.Url.ToString())" />
        <rewrite-uri template="/" />
        <choose>
            <!-- CSRF-token only required for every operation other than GET or HEAD -->
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Method != "GET" && context.Request.Method != "HEAD")">
                <!-- Creating a HEAD subrequest to save request overhead and get the SAP CSRF token and cookie.-->
                <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="SAPCSRFToken" timeout="10" ignore-error="false">
                    <set-url>@(context.Request.Url.ToString())</set-url>
                    <set-method>HEAD</set-method>
                    <set-header name="X-CSRF-Token" exists-action="override">
                        <value>Fetch</value>
                    </set-header>
                    <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
                        <value>@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization"))</value>
                    </set-header>
                </send-request>
                <!-- Extract the token and cookie from the "SAPCSRFToken" and set as header in the POST request. -->
                <choose>
                    <when condition="@(((IResponse)context.Variables["SAPCSRFToken"]).StatusCode == 200)">
                        <set-header name="X-CSRF-Token" exists-action="override">
                            <value>@(((IResponse)context.Variables["SAPCSRFToken"]).Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-csrf-token"))</value>
                        </set-header>
                        <set-header name="Cookie" exists-action="override">
                            <value>@{
                    string rawcookie = ((IResponse)context.Variables["SAPCSRFToken"]).Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Set-Cookie");
                    string[] cookies = rawcookie.Split(';');
                                /* new session sends a XSRF cookie */
                    string xsrftoken = cookies.FirstOrDefault( ss => ss.Contains("sap-XSRF"));
                                /* existing sessions sends a SessionID. No other cases anticipated at this point. Please create a GitHub Pull-Request if you encounter uncovered settings. */
                                if(xsrftoken == null){
                                    xsrftoken = cookies.FirstOrDefault( ss => ss.Contains("SAP_SESSIONID"));
                                }
                                
                    return xsrftoken.Split(',')[1];}</value>
                        </set-header>
                    </when>
                </choose>
            </when>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your code, not an image of your code?

Comment: i have posted the code for reference